# What should the URL format be for an Azure Precompiled Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

What should the URL format be for an Azure Precompiled Function?

I've download a clean copy of the example code of using precompiled Function Apps at [FunctionsAsWebProject](https://github.com/lindydonna/FunctionsAsWebProject)

Deployed to my test Azure account, but doesn't appear to be working ... *Ok, more accurately, I can't get it to work* :-)

I've tried the URL ... https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HelloHttpTrigger ... in a similar vein to the existing C# script based Function App calls

From a "standard" Function App I get the expected "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"

But from the pre-compiled, just get a 404 ...

Checked in Kudo, and the **function.json** file is in the **HelloHttpTrigger** folder, and the **FunctionsLibraryProject.dll** is in the \bin folder

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\FunctionsLibraryProject.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionsLibraryProject.HelloHttpTrigger.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the code for the method ...

```
namespace FunctionsLibraryProject
{
    public class HelloHttpTrigger
    {
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
                                HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
         ......
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL is shown under `Get function URL` button. But generally, I think your URL is correct.

404 probably means you have a compilation/wiring error in the function. Go to the portal and try to run it from there, see if there are any errors.

If you uploaded `function.json` before the binary assembly, you might need to restart the web app or change `function.json` again - I once got stuck on "scriptFile is point to wrong path" kind of error that way.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but this is option only seems to be available in the "Function Apps" blade. The precompiled Functions are deployed as web apps, so appear in the App Service blade ... well they are in my try out

Comment: @SteveC This shouldn't be like you describe! They should be part of Function App, visible and runable from the portal. Try adding a Function App from the portal, then add a function, change `function.json` and upload the `dll`.

Comment: My confusion is the example at https://github.com/lindydonna/FunctionsAsWebProject describes it as "Example of a Web App project for Azure Functions", so I assumed it was a web app and deployed it as such

Comment: Yeap, I can get the precompile Functions DLL working in an existing Function App by manually uploading it, following notes at ... https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2017/01/building-testing-deploying-precompiled-azure-functions/ ...